# Previewing the xslt to pdf transformation in html

Tags: java, html, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have already created code and xslt to convert from XML to pdf using Apache FOP. Now I need to preview the pdf on changing the xslt. It should be viewed as Html page. I am unable to do it. Can anyone please help me with it. Thank you.

The below code is for other data for trial I have added A P J Abdul Kalam

**xslt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin="1cm">
          <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="1cm"/>
          <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="1cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
            <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Helvetica" color="green" font-size="16pt" font-weight="bold"><xsl:value-of select="data/title"/></fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block text-align="right" font-size="11pt">Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="last-page"/></fo:block>
            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="8pt">Copyright&#169; 2022 Creation, All rights Reserved</fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block text-align="justify" font-family="Helvetica" color="black" font-size="13pt" space-after="3mm">
                <xsl:value-of select="data/Para"/>
            </fo:block>
            
            <fo:block text-align="justify" font-family="Helvetica" color="black" font-size="13pt" space-after="3mm">
                <xsl:value-of select="data/Para[2]"/>
            </fo:block>
            
            <fo:block text-align="justify" font-family="Helvetica" color="black" font-size="13pt" space-after="3mm">
                <xsl:value-of select="data/Para[3]"/>
            </fo:block>
          
            <fo:block text-align="justify" font-family="Helvetica" color="black" font-size="13pt" space-after="3mm">The details have been fetched from 
            <fo:basic-link font-family="Helvetica" color="red" font-size="11pt" font-weight="bold" external-destination="url(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam)"> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam</fo:basic-link></fo:block>
          
            <fo:block id="last-page"/>
        </fo:flow>         
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**data xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <title>A P J Abdul Kalam</title>
    <url>https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A._P._J._Abdul_Kalam</url>
    <Para>
          Avul Pakir Jainulabdeen Abdul Kalam;was born on 15 October 1931 – 27 July 2015) was an Indian aerospace scientist 
          who served as the 11th president of India from 2002 to 2007. He was born and raised in Rameswaram, Tamil Nadu and studied physics and aerospace engineering. 
          He spent the next four decades as a scientist and science administrator, mainly at the Defence Research and Development Organisation (DRDO) and 
          Indian Space Research Organisation (ISRO) and was intimately involved in India's civilian space programme and military missile development efforts. 
          He thus came to be known as the Missile Man of India for his work on the development of ballistic missile and launch vehicle technology. He also played a 
          pivotal organisational, technical, and political role in India's Pokhran-II nuclear tests in 1998, the first since the original nuclear test by India in 1974.
    </Para> 
    <Para>
          Kalam was elected as the 11th president of India in 2002 with the support of both the ruling Bharatiya Janata Party and the then-opposition Indian 
          National Congress. Widely referred to as the "People's President",[6] he returned to his civilian life of education, writing and public service after a single 
          term. He was a recipient of several prestigious awards, including the Bharat Ratna, India's highest civilian honour.
    </Para>   
    <Para>
          While delivering a lecture at the Indian Institute of Management Shillong, Kalam collapsed and died from an apparent cardiac arrest on 27 July 2015, 
          aged 83. Thousands, including national-level dignitaries, attended the funeral ceremony held in his hometown of Rameswaram, where he was buried with full state 
          honours.
    </Para>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers render HTML. XSL FO is not HTML and does not render in the browser. The only *real* solution to your request is to render it to PDF server side and show them the PDF. That should be fairly easy, is that your issue? If it is show the server-side code you are using to generate PDF and send it back to the browser.

If you are thinking that you can mimic the PDF through XSL FO to HTML conversion. Forget it. It isn't *real*. No real kerning, fonts have to be the same and many other limitations (keeps, pages, etc.)

You can write HTML that does not even render the same in Safari, Firefox, Edge and Chrome. Thinking you can then introduce converting XSL FO to HTML for preview is a dream.

Some engines support SVG paginated output or XHTML output that attempts to mimic the conversion, but it is only as best as the browser is in rendering the content.